# Converting string to number in C

Tags: c, strcat

I'm trying to write a program which converts lower cased alphabet to numerical digits.
    a -> 01
    b -> 02
    ...
    z -> 26

For the first nine letters I need to put a 0 before the number.

This is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


#define MAXLEN 128

void s2n(char str[])
{

  int i;
  char x;
  char result[256];

  for (i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    x = str[i];
    x = x - 96;


    if (x < 10) {

      char src[2] = {0, x};
      strcat(result, src);
    }
    else {
      char src2[1] = {x};
      strcat(result, src2);
    }

    printf("%s",  result);

  }

}

int main(void)
{
  char str[MAXLEN];

  printf("Lower cased string please: ", MAXLEN);
  scanf("%s", str);

  s2n(str);

  return 0;

}
```

Could you tell me what is wrong with my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see is:

```
  char src[2] = {0, x};
```

You want to use the *character* 0, rather than the byte value 0 (NUL):

```
  char src[2] = {'0', x};
```

Also, you need to NUL terminate your `src` array:

```
  char src[] = {'0', x, 0};
```

The NUL termination would need to be done in both cases.

Another problem is your `x = x - 96` statement also does not take into account that the character 0 is different from the byte value 0. So

```
x = x - 96 + '0';
```

would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You use `strcat()` on an uninitialized array, `result`, it doesn't work that way, `strcat()` looks for the terminating `nul` byte in it's first parameter, and glues the second parameter from that point.

In your case there is no `'\0'` in result, calling `strcat()` with `result` as the first parameter causes undefined behavior.

You should at least ensure that there is one `'\0'` in result, you can do that by just setting the first element of `result` to `'\0'`, like

```
result[0] = '\0';
```

Right before the loop starts, also you pass the second paramter `src` which is an array but is not a string, because it has no terminating `'\0'`, but you actually don't need an array nor `strcat()`.

You can use an index variable and just assing the `i`th element of the array to the actual character computed from the original value, like

```
result[i] = x;
```

Then you don't `nul` terminate `result`, which causes undefined behavior when you try to print `resutl`.

You also passing a parameter to `printf()` where it's not expecting one, that indicates that you are either silencing or ignoring compiler warnings.

There are many problems in your code, the following code, does what you want

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void s2n(char chr)
{
    char result[4];
    if (snprintf(result, sizeof(result), "%02d", 1 + chr - 'a') >= sizeof(result))
        return;
    printf("%s",  result);
}

int main(void)
{
    char chr;

    printf("Lower cased string please: ");
    if (scanf(" %c", &chr) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "input error!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    s2n(chr);

    return 0;
}
```

note that no strings are required except the one where you are going to store the result, which you can build easily with `sprintf()`.